# @Value annotated field returning null method of @Service annotated class

Tags: spring-boot, spring-annotations

I'm facing a strange issue while accessing a property using @Value annotation in a @Service annotated class with Spring Boot 2.2.1.RELEASE. The field is resolving to null and I'm not sure how to debug it.

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Value("${my.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${my.password}")
    private String password;

    private RestTemplate restTemplate = getRestTemplate();


    private RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
    final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    log.debug("Generating NTCredentials for RestTemplate using user: {} and password: {}", username, password);
    credentialsProvider
        .setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
            new NTCredentials(username, password, null, "DOMAIN"));

    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setHttpClient(client);
    return new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);
    }

}
```

In this code, inside the getRestTemplate() method the username and password are always coming as null.
I have confirmed that the properties are present in the application.properties file.

Any help would be really appreciated!

**Edit 1:**

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Value("${my.url}")
    private String url;

    private String username;
    private String password;

    private RestTemplate restTemplate  = getRestTemplate();

    public MyService(@Value("${my.username}") String username, @Value("${my.password}") String password) {
    System.out.println(">> Inside Constructor");
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    }

    public String updateDetails(String data) {
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(data);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
    return response.getBody();

    }

    private RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
    System.out.println(">> Inside RestTemplate Method");
    final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    log.debug("Generating NTCredentials for RestTemplate using user: {} and password: {}", username, password);
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new NTCredentials(username, password, null, "DOMAIN"));

    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setHttpClient(client);
    return new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);
    }

}
```

Logs :

```
2019-11-25 19:56:47.069  INFO 20336 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1293 ms
>> Inside RestTemplate Method
2019-11-25 19:56:47.361 DEBUG 20336 --- [  restartedMain] c.d.u.u.services.MyService       : Generating NTCredentials for RestTemplate using user: null and password: null
>> Inside Constructor
[2
```

As you see, the getRestTemplate() is getting called before the constructor is getting called. Also, the user and password values are coming as null inside the getRestTemplate() method. However, if I do the initialization of the restTemplate inside the constructor then everything works fine.

```
this.restTemplate = getRestTemplate();
```

I thought the constructor was always called first. Could someone please explain this?

Comment: Use constructor injection and you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `getRestTemplate();` at the same time the class level field is being declared, which is before the class has been inflated by Spring framework, thus the properties aren't yet available.

Try setting the values in the class's constructor instead. You can do this by changing your variable declaration to : `private RestTemplate restTemplate;` and adding this constructor:

```
public MyService() {
    this.restTemplate = getRestTemplate();
}
```

Comment: *fully inflated the MyService class as well as any other beans* that is simply false.

Comment: I tried this but still, the username and password fields are coming as null.

Comment: @noobCoder Are properties getting pulled into any other classes successfully? Have you verified that the properties file is in src/main/resources?

Comment: @NickJordan yeah other classes are working fine. In fact, in this same class, I have another method that uses a @ Value annotated method and that is working fine.

Comment: @noobCoder Ok gotcha, so if you have another method working with @ Value in the same class I am going to assume the method doesn't get called as part of class level variable instantiation and instead gets called in normal processing once the classes are all inflated. The problem is that the values of those properties are not yet available in Spring's ApplicationContext when the class is getting inflated. You could use constructor injection with this answer like you mentioned in a comment of one of the above answers, or you could...

Comment: @noobCoder ... explicitly inflate this class as a @ Bean from a @ Configuration annotated class. In a config class like this, the bean inflation happens before Spring tries to call any other class's constructor, so you would have access to the @ Value class level fields just fine in a config class, and could pass these values to a constructor of the MyService class and return this newed up object as a @ Bean.

Sort of hard to explain in comments, I can post another answer with example code if you'd like

Answer (score 1):

Use constructor injection

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    @Autowired // optional if it is only single constructor
    public MyService(@Value("${my.username}") String username, @Value("${my.password}") String password){
        this.username=username;
        this.password=password;
         ///its already here
    }
```

This way you are **guaranteed** that values must be provided and available on object construction - thus it will be later on when you will call any of methods of that class.

If values are not provided OR SpEL is invalid, app will not boot.

Comment: Thanks! 
I tried using constructor injection as you suggested but the issue is still there.
However, I was able to get the values by combining your and @Nick Jordan's solution. I used constructor injection and then called getRestTemplate() method from within the constructor.

Comment: Also, in the code snippet I posted above, I added a constructor with a print statement and added a print statement to the getRestTemplate() method.

I see that the getRestTemplate() method is getting executed before the constructor. I thought constructor would be called first. Could you please help me understand this?

Comment: I don't see related code. And yes, constructor is always first by its nature.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the way you are accessing the restTemplate for instantiating the private variable.  I do it this way.

```
@Autowire private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Bean public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
  ...
}
```

This way Spring has control over when variables are instantiated.